# how to calculate the average moisture flux over a period of time

Tags: meteorology

I wanna calculate the average moisture flux over a period of time. For example the average moisture flux over an entire summer. I don't have a meteorological background. I have a conceptual confusion about the average moisture flux: 
In case, a site has a moisture flux toward due north with a magnitude of 50 on the first day. It has a moisture flux toward due south with a magnitude of 50 on the second day. Thus, the average moisture flux over these two days is zero? Is it a correct understanding?
Could you guys give me some useful hints or info?

Comment: I'd think for a time average, you'd tend to look at an average of magnitude rather than the vectors themselves?  Otherwise it'd be like averaging velocity vectors from a trip around the country and getting 0... not very meaningful in most situations.  Then maybe make like a wind rose or such of the various directions.  But unfortunately it's not something I have a great amount of expertise in, and would depend on the topic of interest I'd think.

Comment: Yes. It mostly depends on the topic of interest.
For me, I center on the summer. There is always a previlent wind direction in this season. @JeopardyTempest

Comment: Maybe the wind rose is a preliminary and important step to have a statistically basic understanding of my interest.